# Node's and Electron's modules from inside Angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, electron

I am developing an **Electron** application using **Angular2**.

In the electron's `main.js` I am referencing/loading the NG App:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url')

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})

  // load the index.html of the NG app:
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../../dist/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }))

[...]
```

This works like a charm. However, I'd now like to access node's and electron's modules from **inside the NG part**.

When I try to import e.g.: the `fs` module like:

```
import * as fs from "fs";
```

It still compiles but whenever I call `fs.readFile(...)` it says:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_fs__.readFile is not a function
```

When I think about it, this does not and can not work since the modules are not inside the `node_modules` folder (right?).
What do I need to do to make them available inside the NG part?

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still relevant -

I don't know of an "official" way for this yet. but there are work-around solutions - mainly around requiring electron/other modules in index.html and accessing `window['electron']` -

```
<script>
    window.electron = require('electron');
</script>
```

---

or creating an angular services accessing the electron object.

```
declare const window: ElectronWindow;
export class ChildProcessService {...}
```

You can see an implementaion of this [Here](https://github.com/Inoverse/ngx-childprocess)

- `ElectronWindow` refers to a custom interface you can create and add a require() function to for handling typings.
- use `window.require(*some-node-module*)` to store modules

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Electron / Node modules directly from inside Angular. Instead, check out [the Electron remote API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md).

Comment: Unfortunately I can not even access the `electron` module to load the `remote` from: `import {remote} from "electron";` throws: `Cannot find name 'electron'`